# What are some good approaches for predicting sub-state level population changes before census data is released

Tags: data-request, usa, us-census, demographics, census

I am currently working with US census data from 2013 at the latest. I am very interested in getting population and other demographic data pertaining to 2014 and   Early 2015 as soon as possible. What approaches have people used in the past to get a sense of where the major Demographic changes are happening before the official census data is released?

NOTE: I'm interested in geographically specific information. Any information about US areas that is any less specific than the city or county level is not of any interest to me

Answer (score 2):

The two commercial databases to visit are:

- [InfoGroup](http://www.referenceusa.com/): These guys consolidate information on residents, including demographics and where you buy your cat food. Go to your library to run queries.
- [Woodes & Poole](https://www.woodsandpoole.com/main.php?cat=country): These guys provide a no nonsense product at a fee, but I have had no problems with their products. Here is a link for the [2015 estimates of MSA's](https://www.woodsandpoole.com/main.php?cat=country)
- A tertriary option is to do forecasts using the Regional Economic Models, Inc [(REMI)](http://www.remi.com/) economic forecasting tool.

Additionally, most states perform economic models to develop population projections at the county and sometime MSA level. These are put together by Department of Revenues, Department of Commerce, or Business Research departments. The update cycles for these vary, the one from Utah was last done in 2012, but can be compensated by performing interpolations.

A sampling of these

- [Alabama](http://cber.cba.ua.edu/edata/est_prj.html), through its Center for Business and Economic Research,
- [California](http://www.dof.ca.gov/research/demographic/reports/projections/view.php), through its Department of Finance,
- [Florida](http://www.bebr.ufl.edu/sites/default/files/population/FPS%20172.pdf), through its Bureau of Economic and Business Research,
- [Montana](http://ceic.mt.gov/Population/PopProjectionsTitlePage.aspx), through its Department of Commerce,
- [Utah](http://gomb.utah.gov/budget-policy/demographic-economic-analysis/) Through its Governor's Office of 
  Management & Budget